# As something begins, after

Tags: riddle, word

here's a riddle.

Clue 1:

> Some watches

Clue 2:

> Something about an horseshoe

Clue 3:

> Five are enough

Clue 4:

> A contrast for the first

**Who am I?**

Answer (score 1):

Are you a

> Nail

Some watches

> Some watches have tiny nails in them

Something about an horseshoe

> Nails are used to secure horseshoes to horse's hooves

Five are enough

> 5 fingernails are enough for each hand

A contrast for the first

> Nail time -- The time devoted to decorating finger/ toenails with nail polish or nail varnish. A lot of time is spent/wasted, contrast to the reason you have a watch.

Comment: I consider this answer full of valid matches and I can honestly say that it is very full of efforts. But despite these aspects, this is not the answer I expected. Keep trying :)